# Why disabling mapping doesn't work in my vim editor?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

In my vim editor, I can find two mappings of  through following commands:

```
:imap <CR>
```

and it outputs:

```
i  <CR>        &@<SNR>60_AutoPairsOldCRWrapper73<SNR>60_AutoPairsReturn
i  <CR>          <CR><Plug>DiscretionaryEnd
```

I want to disable the first one, so I add it into my .vimrc file:

```
iunmap <buffer> <CR>
```

but vim shows error `no such mapping` error when I open my editor, but actually I can disable the mapping by typing command in editor:

```
:iunmap <buffer> <CR>
```

I want to know why I cann't make it work in my .vimrc configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

Plugins are sourced after your `vimrc` so the mapping you want to disable is not defined when that comand is executed.

That said, the plugin's README tells you how to replace the default mappings. So… read it and experiment.

Comment: See `:h g:AutoPairsMapCR`